# What state is kept between JavaScript lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I was wondering what states are kept between two lines of JavaScript code submitted to `babel-node`. My confusion arises because if you write two lines of code, you can override an variable definition without an error. For example, with `babel-node --presets es2015`, you can do:

```
> const a = 1;
undefined
> let a = 2;
undefined
```

Now if you write it in one line, you get an error:

```
> const a = 1; let a = 2;
TypeError: repl: Duplicate declaration "a"
...
```

It seems that in the first case, the state that `a` is defined as `1` (`const` variable assignment) is lost (yet not until the second assignment), while in the second case, it is maintained.

What causes the differences here? and which states are maintained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `const` and `let` are new syntaxes, they must be transpiled to the only binding mechanism that was available before ES6: `var`. In which case, `var` allows all sorts of haphazard reassignment without generating any kind of warning.

So when you type an expression in `babel-node`, babel transpiles it, evaluates it, then displays the result. Babel can check for misuse of a `const` binding at transpile time, which is why you're seeing the error for `const a = 1; let a = 2`. But `const a = 1` and `let a = 2`, when transpiled/evaluated as separate expressions, will not exhibit the error because babel is not able to detect a problem in either expression alone.

---

A more visual demonstration of the issue: For every expression `expr` you type in the `babel-node` REPL,  this is essentially what's happening

```
evaluate(transpile(expr))
// => someResult
```

So you won't see an error here

```
evaluate(transpile('const a = 1'))
evaluate('var a = 1')
// bind a to 1
// return undefined

evaluate(transpile('let a = 2'))
evaluate('var a = 2')
// bind a to 2
// return undefined
```

But you will see an error here

```
evaluate(transpile('const a = 1; let a = 2'))
// ERROR during transpile: const a has already been declared
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not use `babel-repl`, but it must be something to do with the conversion it is doing because everything works as expected with the regular REPL:

```
$ node -v
v7.4.0

$ node
> const a = 1;
undefined
> let a = 1;
SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared

> const b = 1; let b = 1;
const b = 1; let b = 1;
                     ^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared

> .editor
// Entering editor mode (^D to finish, ^C to cancel)
const c = 1;
let c = 1;

let c = 1;
        ^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'c' has already been declared
```

Comment: spot on with `babel-node` being the specific culprit – the vanilla `node` repl does not exhibit this issue.