# What state is kept between JavaScript code blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I read (from "JavaScript, the good parts") that JavaScript has no block scopes, and it is even suggested to declare variables inside a function at its very beginning instead of inside `{ }`'s to avoid confusion.

However, I am confused by an example (simplified here) that I just encountered and tested using `babel-node --presets es2015`:

```
> {const a = 1;}; {const a = 2;};
undefined
> a;
1
```

Here, the two `const` variable assignments made in one line would generate an error if they hadn't been enclosed in blocks `{}` as discussed in my previous question [What state is kept between JavaScript lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275202) (so that separate transpilation shouldn't be an issue).

However, when used in code blocks, no error is generated. And as shown above, the second assignment seems  to have no effect at all.

The behavior in `node` is also interesting,

```
> {const a = 1;}; {const a = 2;};
undefined
> a;
ReferenceError: a is not defined
...
```

It's as if the two code blocks didn't happen, `a` is not defined. So:

Why is enclosing statements in code blocks induce different behavior above (i.e. errors go away)?

What's remembered/forgotten between the code blocks?

Which behavior among `babel-node` and `node` is correct or standard-compliant?

FYI, versions are:

```
$ node --version
v7.10.0
~$ babel-node --version
6.24.1
```

Comment: JavaScript variables (`var`) _are not block scoped_.  For block scoping you must use `const` or `let`.

Comment: Maybe `babel-node --presets es2015` doesn't apply block scoping to `const`? The shown behavior in node seems consistent with what you'd expect. `a` should be `undefined`.

Comment: In the first example `a` should be `undefined`. If not, this is a fault with babel.

Comment: this is fault with babel scoping . check out js translated with babel - it uses var in block scope. that why you get the result

Comment: I'm curious: How did you learn about `const` without also learning that it is block scoped?

Comment: @FelixKling `How did you learn about const without also learning that it is block scoped?`. - I am still learning my ropes about ES6 and its toolchains. Hence the question. I learned `const` keyword in a tutorial/blog, which didn't mention that it's block scoped.

Comment: @FelixKling  In case you are curious, from Eric Elliott's "A Functional Programmer’s Introduction to JavaScript (Composing Software)": `It's a signal that tells you, "the value assigned to this name is not going to change". It helps you fully understand what the name means right away, without needing to read the whole function or block scope.`

Comment: I see. Seems understandable if the tutorial isn't explicitly about new features of ES6. In that case I would advise to try to find information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) when you encounter unfamiliar syntax. Those articles should be more complete. Of course sometimes you simply don't know what to look for `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` and `let` are indeed meant to be block-scoped (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)) - however, in your first example, Babel compiles the code down to a form that will work in browsers from the dark days before that syntax existed<sup>1</sup>:

```
"use strict";

{
  var a = 1;
};{
  var _a = 2;
};
```

As evolutionxbox pointed out in the comments, `var` is *not* block scoped, so this causes some slightly non-standard behavior. Note that the second `a` gets renamed to avoid a name conflict - this is why `a` evaluates to `1` outside of the block and not `2`.

Babel could theoretically wrap the blocks in a IIFE or something to properly simulate the block scoping, but I presume they decided it wasn't worth that level of code bloat for something so minor.

Node, on the other hand, implements `const` and `let` natively, rather than converting it to `var` statements, so you get standards-compliant behavior there.

---

<sup>1. You can view what code gets generated by Babel easily by using their [online REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) - that tends to be my first port of call if I'm not sure why my compiled code is acting in a certain way.</sup>

Comment: `so this causes some slightly non-standard behavior.` Thanks for the clarification and pointers.

Comment: @tinlyx: Glad I could help! I've used Babel with Node before but I'd never noticed this behaviour, interesting to see the trade-offs made between standards compliance and practicality.

Answer (score 2):

"JavaScript, the good parts" was written and published (2008) before `const` and `let` were a thing in JavaScript (they arrived in ES6). Both of these will allow you to make block-scoped variables. Also `var` still works exactly the same (it isn't block-scoped and its definition gets hoisted to the top of the nearest (function) scope).

Comment: May you mention a reason as to why the first example allows `a` to be logged outside of a block?